# Vertical alignment of text and picture

Tags: tables, beamer

I want to align “My text” (in vertical) with picture in the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}

\mode<article> % only for the article version
{
  \usepackage{fullpage}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
}


\mode<presentation>
{
  %\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][bottom=red!10,top=blue!10]
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \usefonttheme{serif}
  \usecolortheme{crane}
}

\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\setbeamertemplate{items}[circle]

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,positioning,fit,backgrounds,shapes.geometric}

\newcommand\drawnestedsets[4]{
  % initial position
  \def\position{#1}
  % number of sets
  \def\nbsets{#2}
  % list of sets
  \def\listofnestedsets{#3}
  % reversed list of colors
  \def\reversedlistofcolors{#4}

  % position and draw labels of sets
  \coordinate (circle-0) at (#1);
  \coordinate (set-0) at (#1);
  \foreach \set [count=\c] in \listofnestedsets {
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\cminusone}{\c - 1}
    % label of current set (below previous nested set)
    \node[below=3pt of circle-\cminusone,inner sep=0]
    (set-\c) {\set};
    % current set (fit current label and previous set)
    \node[circle,inner sep=0,fit=(circle-\cminusone)(set-\c)]
    (circle-\c) {};
  }

  % draw and fill sets in reverse order
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \foreach \col[count=\c] in \reversedlistofcolors {
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\invc}{\nbsets-\c}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\invcplusone}{\invc+1}
      \node[circle,draw,fill=\col,inner sep=0,
      fit=(circle-\invc)(set-\invcplusone)] {};
    }
  \end{scope}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tabular}{lr}
  %\hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  \begin{minipage}{8.0cm}
My text
\end{minipage}
  & %\resizebox{3.0cm}{0.5cm}{
  \resizebox{3.0cm}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\drawnestedsets{0,-1}{4}{A,
B,C,D}{blue!50,red!50,yellow!50,orange}
\end{tikzpicture}}
  %\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Any help is welcome.

[image]

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot to your question of the codes result? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `baseline=...` key of the `tikzpicture` to adjust the vertical alignment:

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}

\mode<article> % only for the article version
{
  \usepackage{fullpage}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
}


\mode<presentation>
{
  %\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][bottom=red!10,top=blue!10]
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \usefonttheme{serif}
  \usecolortheme{crane}
}

\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\setbeamertemplate{items}[circle]

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,positioning,fit,backgrounds,shapes.geometric}

\newcommand\drawnestedsets[4]{
  % initial position
  \def\position{#1}
  % number of sets
  \def\nbsets{#2}
  % list of sets
  \def\listofnestedsets{#3}
  % reversed list of colors
  \def\reversedlistofcolors{#4}

  % position and draw labels of sets
  \coordinate (circle-0) at (#1);
  \coordinate (set-0) at (#1);
  \foreach \set [count=\c] in \listofnestedsets {
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\cminusone}{\c - 1}
    % label of current set (below previous nested set)
    \node[below=3pt of circle-\cminusone,inner sep=0]
    (set-\c) {\set};
    % current set (fit current label and previous set)
    \node[circle,inner sep=0,fit=(circle-\cminusone)(set-\c)]
    (circle-\c) {};
  }

  % draw and fill sets in reverse order
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \foreach \col[count=\c] in \reversedlistofcolors {
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\invc}{\nbsets-\c}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\invcplusone}{\invc+1}
      \node[circle,draw,fill=\col,inner sep=0,
      fit=(circle-\invc)(set-\invcplusone)] {};
    }
  \end{scope}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tabular}{lr}
  %\hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  \begin{minipage}{8.0cm}
My text
\end{minipage}
  & %\resizebox{3.0cm}{0.5cm}{
  \resizebox{3.0cm}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-2cm]
\drawnestedsets{0,-1}{4}{A,
B,C,D}{blue!50,red!50,yellow!50,orange}
\end{tikzpicture}}
  %\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]